# Drawing area with ScrollView

Tags: java, android, android-activity, draw

I´m creating a painting and drawing area in my Activity and I would like to move it with a scrollView.

If I have this code I don´t have any problem:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameVer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="2000dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null">

    <package.DrawingView
        android:id="@+id/drawing"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2000dip"
        android:background="@null" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

But, if I add the ScrollView, it paints in pieces:

```
<package.LinkableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="2000dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameVer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2000dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@null">

            <package.DrawingView
                android:id="@+id/drawing"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="2000dip"
                android:background="@null" />

        </RelativeLayout>
</package.LinkableScrollView>
```

[image]

If I paint in portrait mode, it lets me draw, but in pieces, and if I paint in landscape I can paint perfectly.

I have created mi own ScrollView with the enabling or disabling property, but it paints in the same way.

```
public class LinkableScrollView extends ScrollView {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_FINGERS_TO_ACTIVATE_SCROLL = 2;
    private boolean doubleDrag = false;
    private boolean enableScrolling = true;

    public LinkableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)       {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public LinkableScrollView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public LinkableScrollView(Context context) {
       super(context);
    }

    private int getScrollHeight() {
        return super.getChildAt(0).getHeight() - super.getHeight();
    }

    public boolean isEnableScrolling() {
       return enableScrolling;
    }

    public void setEnableScrolling(boolean enableScrolling) {
       this.enableScrolling = enableScrolling;
    }



     @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {

        if (isEnableScrolling()) {
            int action = event.getAction();

            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    super.onTouchEvent(event);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    super.onTouchEvent(event);
                   doubleDrag = false;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (event.getPointerCount() == NUMBER_OF_FINGERS_TO_ACTIVATE_SCROLL) {
                        doubleDrag = true;
                    }
                    if (doubleDrag) {
                       super.onTouchEvent(event);
                    }
            }
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }


    }
}
```

Draw touch event:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    Point p = new Point();
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            drawPath.reset();
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;
}
```

Please, can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: Its laggy is what you meant? Or the scroll and the draw is smooth but you miss the draw at times??

Comment: No, it draws at first and when you still moving your finger, it doesn´t draw.